# how to configure ngram tokenizer for searching words with periods

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize

Given that the following html text is stored in a document field within the lucene index, I would like to be able to do a query_string query for either "jquery" or "jquery.min" or "jquery.min.js" and have a hit returned.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is what I am using for the tokenizer on the index now:

```
        "tokenizer" : {
            "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                "type" : "nGram",
                "min_gram" : "3",
                "max_gram" : "8",
                "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit", "punctuation"]
            }
        }
```

The problem I am encountering is that I can search "jquery" or "jquery.min.ms" but not "jquery.min" for a search result.

Is there a way to tokenize in lucene so that all three of those queries would return a result?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing the rest of your setup, but here is a setup that worked for me. It doesn't return the document for the query `"jquery.min.ms"`, though, so something is different about your setup from what I'm doing. If you can post your full mapping (or enough of it to capture the essence of the problem) maybe I can help further.

Here is what I did. I used the [keyword analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) for searching, along with your ngram tokenizer for indexing. I increased the size of the `"max_gram"` to `10`, since that's the size of `"jquery.min"`. Using the `keyword` analyzer means the query will not be tokenized but only used to match against index tokens. This may or may not be what you want, depending on your use case.

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
            "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": "3",
               "max_gram": "10",
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "my_text": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "my_text": "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
    "my_text": "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.0/angular-material.min.js\"></script>"
}

POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "default_field": "my_text",
         "query": "jquery.min"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.0390625,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.0390625,
            "_source": {
               "my_text": "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/adc96befb466c1ec2e02685cc716b198e154b94e

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your configuration causes the same behavior as mine.  I'm now looking into the fact that I am returning only highlight entries and not the _source.  Interesting!